# Get the cursor position in the AJAX HTML editor

Tags: c#, ajax, editor

I am using the ajax html editor in my aspx page. I wanted to insert an image at the given cursor position. How can i get the cursor position.
As of now I am able to insert the image at the end of the editor by creating a  tag and adding it to the content.